# Number Theory Eulers phi Function of n^2

Tags: elementary-number-theory

https://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/~lavric/Tattersall%20-%20Elementary%20number%20theory%20in%20nine%20chapters.pdf

Page 168 #9.... this seems completely obvious to me? how do i prove this concretely?

Comment: If it is completely obvious, then why is what you have done unsatisfactory.  What have you done?

Comment: When giving a reference page-exercise in a book, one should always provide the reference in the page enumeration *of the book*, not the one of the pdf file.

Comment: @DougM I had done what you wrote below! Just seemed to simple but I guess thats the way it is meant to be done! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$n$ has some prime fatorization.

$n = p_1^rp_2^s\cdots p_k^z\\
\phi (n) = n\frac {p_1 - 1}{p_1}\frac {p_2-1}{p_2}\cdots\frac {p_k-1}{p_k}\\
n^2 = p_1^{2r}p_2^{2s}\cdots p_k^{2z}\\
\phi (n^2) = n^2\frac {p_1 - 1}{p_1}\frac {p_2-1}{p_2}\cdots\frac {p_k-1}{p_k} = n\phi(n)$